# free an array of strings gives SIGABRT

Tags: c, free

I am trying to free an array of strings in this manner:

```
unsigned char **strings = words.strings;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfWords; ++i) {
    free(strings + i);
}
```

but I get a `SIGABRT` (error code 134) with the message:

> free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001c69018

However if I do this:

```
unsigned char **strings = words.strings;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfWords; ++i) {
    free(strings[i]);
}
```

then everything works just fine.

Can someone point me the difference? Shouldn't these two forms be equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first snippet, you missed to dereference the pointer.

```
free(strings + i);
```

should be

```
free(*(strings + i));
```

In case of `free(strings + i);` you are trying to increment the pointer-to-pointer, i.e., the `string` itself. Actually, what you want is to free each *valid* element pointed by `string` which are given by `string[i]`. So, `string[i]` is basically de-referencing the pointer `string` to get all the elements pointed by it.

Comment: Yes, it was so obvious!

Comment: I should not have asked the question. I should have spent more time on it. The idea is that the whole string array got wiped out when I did free(strings + 0). But when it did free(strings + 1) the program thrown an SIGABRT

Comment: @Kay Thanks to you too. :)